# cargo build of the same code: spurious compile time errors?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have crate `A` that depend on `B` and `B` depend on [rust-nmea](https://github.com/Dushistov/rust-nmea) crate.

If I build crate `A` I got bunch of errors (all of them that missed `use std::error::Error;`) during build of [rust-nmea](https://github.com/Dushistov/rust-nmea) dependency:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `description` found for type `nom::Err<&[u8]>` in the current scope
   --> /home/evgeniy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/nmea-0.0.6/src/parse.rs:100:44
    |
100 |                      IError::Error(e) => e.description().to_string(),
    |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
    = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
            candidate #1: `use std::error::Error;`
```

But if I go to source tree of `B` crate and run `cargo build`,
all build without any error (if you follow me `A` depend on `B` and `B` depend on [rust-nmea](https://github.com/Dushistov/rust-nmea)),

also if go to `/home/evgeniy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/nmea-0.0.6/` (see compile error) and run `cargo build` then all good.

cargo tree show for `A`:

```
│   ├── chrono v0.4.0
│   │   ├── num v0.1.40
│   │   │   ├── num-integer v0.1.35
│   │   │   │   └── num-traits v0.1.40
│   │   │   ├── num-iter v0.1.34
│   │   │   │   ├── num-integer v0.1.35 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── num-traits v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   │   └── num-traits v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   └── time v0.1.38
│   │       └── libc v0.2.27
 ├── nmea v0.0.6
    │   ├── chrono v0.4.0 (*)
    │   └── nom v3.2.0
    │       └── memchr v1.0.1 (*)
```

and for cached by `cargo` [rust-nmea](https://github.com/Dushistov/rust-nmea):

```
├── chrono v0.4.0
│   ├── num v0.1.40
│   │   ├── num-integer v0.1.35
│   │   │   └── num-traits v0.1.40
│   │   ├── num-iter v0.1.34
│   │   │   ├── num-integer v0.1.35 (*)
│   │   │   └── num-traits v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   └── num-traits v0.1.40 (*)
│   └── time v0.1.38
│       └── libc v0.2.27
└── nom v3.2.0
    └── memchr v1.0.1
        └── libc v0.2.27 (*)
```

so for both good and bad case used the same dependencies.

If run `cargo build -v -j1`, I got `rustc` command line for both cases.

The only difference for good and bad case is this part:

```
-L dependency=/home/evgeniy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/nmea-0.0.6/target/debug/deps --extern chrono=/home/evgeniy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/nmea-0.0.6/target/debug/deps/libchrono-8e9e54e691d9b988.rlib --extern nom=/home/evgeniy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/nmea-0.0.6/target/debug/deps/libnom-b72336f662b090c1.rlib
```

bad case have different path to libraries and `libnom-e2ec53418967eac0.rlib` instead of `libnom-b72336f662b090c1.rlib`, while `libchrono-8e9e54e691d9b988.rlib` match.

The crates `A` and `B` are close sourced and I can not reduce problem to more simple case. [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) crates not used in `A` and `B` except via [rust-nmea](https://github.com/Geal/nom).
[rust-nmea](https://github.com/Geal/nom) is used in simple way, just `nmea = 0.0.6` in `Cargo.toml`.
No flags or so on things.

Any idea why crate dependecy with the same flags (no flags at all)
may produce or not produce syntax error?

Comment: Blind shot in the dark: are you using rustup, and if you are, have you set local overrides that might be interfering?

Comment: @DK. Yes I used `rustup`, but last override command was: `grep -a override ~/.bash_history | grep rustup | tail -n 1`
`rustup override unset`. Any way to check if `override` still active?

Comment: There's `rustup override list`.

Comment: @DK. ```$ rustup override list
no overrides```

Comment: Another blind shot: have you tried `cargo clean` followed by `cargo update` before running `cargo build` again?  While given the `cargo tree` output it'd be a bit surprising, this could be a case of a stale dependency.

Comment: @JDavidSmith Yeah I do clean rebuild (removed `Cargo.lock` and `target` directory), also I check `nom` version via `Cargo.lock` in case `cargo tree` bug

Answer (score 2):

I found source of problem,
crate `A` has second level dependicies with `cexpr`,
`cexpr` has `nom = {version = "^3", features = ["verbose-errors"] }` in `Cargo.toml`,
`rust-nmea` also depend on `nom`, so we have compile time error.