# How can I prevent Cargo from merging the same dependency with different features?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

After figuring out [cargo build of the same code: spurious compile time errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281538/cargo-build-of-the-same-code-spurious-compile-time-errors), I want to know how to prevent such a problem:

```
$ cargo new feature_merge
$ cargo add nmea
$ cargo check > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "success"
success
$ cargo add cexpr
$ cargo check > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo "failed"
failed
$ cargo rm cexpr && cargo check > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "success"
success
```

I remove/add the dependency without any code modification and this influences the build result.

The source of problem, [as I described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281538/cargo-build-of-the-same-code-spurious-compile-time-errors), is that [cexpr](https://github.com/jethrogb/rust-cexpr) depends on nom like this:

```
nom = {version = "^3", features = ["verbose-errors"] }
```

while [nmea](https://github.com/Dushistov/rust-nmea) describes the dependency like this:

```
nom = "3.1.0"
```

With only nmea as a dependency, Cargo builds nom with one set of features,
while Cargo builds cexpr and nmea against nom with another set of features.

I want a way to prevent such wrong usage of the nmea crate which I maintain.

I'd like a compile time error like `` "`nom` compiled with wrong features" ``, or force Cargo to build two variants of nom.

I tried such thing in `nmea/Cargo.toml`:

```
nom = { version = "3.1.0", default-features = false }
```

This changed nothing; there's still a compile time error when cexpr and nmea are combined.

Comment: It might be worth involving people with more specialized knowledge here; maybe you should consider cross-posting the question to r/rust or the rust user forum, or even opening a bug on the cargo github repository.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I posted https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4323 some time ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known issue, related links:

[cargo issue 1](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4323)

[cargo issue 2](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3620)

[cargo rfc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1841)

the short summary:

> crate's features are supposed to be additive

In other words each feature in crate should only append functionality,
not change API. Unfortunately there no good documentation descrbing this problem,
and no automation for testing of this invariant at least at this moment.
This particular issue is related to `nom` bug ([github issue](https://github.com/Geal/nom/issues/544)),
quote from there:

> The problem here is that, when using "simple errors", the type `nom::simple_errors::Err<E>` is simply a type alias of `nom::ErrorKind<E>`, while with "verbose errors" the type `nom::verbose_errors::Err<E>` is a dedicated enum, so the "with-feature" and "without-feature" interfaces are incompatible.